# count characters frequency in a phrase frequency dict in python 3

Tags: python, dictionary

In my experiences, this is a special work to do. I searched in many different ways but still can't find answer to it.
here the question is.

I have a dict of Chinese phrase frequency.It looks like:

```
{'中国':18950, '我们':16734, '我国':15400, ...}
```

What I need to do is count every single character's frequency, for example:
character '国' appears in two phrases ('中国'and '我国') , so this character's frequency should be:

```
{'国':(18950+15400)}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Sagar V I have no idea so far, I just start learning programming for 2weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way:

```
from collections import Counter

c={'中国':18950, '我们':16734, '我国':15400}
print(Counter([j for k,v in c.items() for i in k for j in [i]*v]))
```

Output:

```
Counter({'国': 34350, '我': 32134, '中': 18950, '们': 16734})
```

Comment: it works as well, and it sorted the result automatically,thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Simple example,

```
d = {'abd':2, 'afd':3}
f = {}
for key in d:
    strlen = len(key)
    for i in range(strlen):
        if key[i] in f:
            f[key[i]] += d[key]
        else:
            f[key[i]] = d[key]

print f  #gives {'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'd': 5, 'f': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'中国':18950, '我们':16734, '我国':15400, ...}

q = 0
for i in d:
    if '国' in i:
        a = (d[i])
    q += a
print(q)
```

Comment: @Julien, this works now, and does not require imports.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

char_dict = defaultdict(int)
for phrase, count in phrase_dict.iteritems():
    for char in phrase:
        char_dict[char] += count
```